# How to adjust table formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I am using Microsoft Word. I am using a table in it, but I'm not able to maintain formatting as shown in the screenshot. Highlighted color shows a  difference in formatting (meaning some Xs are high and some are low or normal).

How can I have the same formatting for the whole table, so all the Xs in the table appear at the same level?

[image: Microsoft Word]

Answer (score 1):

Select a cell, bring up a context menu, and adjust "cell alignment". You can select multiple cells, or even the entire table as I did, to change them all at once.

[image: table context menu - cell alignment]

Comment: I have tried it but no change. some other alternative please

Comment: @student No more ideas. Perhaps if you gave me a means to reproduce this, or at least showed formatting symbols in the screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

If you display formatting (Home tab, type "Show/Hide Editing Marks" in Tell Me box), then you'll probably see an extra carriage return (paragraph mark) in those boxes.

Take a look at the linked image to see the possible cause.

!MS Word extra return in table cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fObr.jpg)

The solution is to delete the carriage return in the table cell.  If you're pasting from the clipboard, you can try turning off "Smart Cut and Paste" or trying different Paste methods and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes you are right. But you told me cause. i need solution dear

Comment: student, I added this to my answer: "...delete the carriage return in the table cell."  Try this and let me know if it works.